# iPhone app rating popup code

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Does anyone know of open source code available to implement a popup to the user after so many days or so many instances of the app to prompt the user to rate and review the app on the app store?

I've seen this already with a few apps I own.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't ideal, i personally find it abit ugly, but it's easy to implement and reactivates when a new version is released and more importantly works.

http://arashpayan.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/

Comment: Thanks Bongeh. Do you recommend an alternative way to try and get users to rate/review the app?

Comment: This is the tool i am using in my apps at the moment, my only issue with it is i think the generic iphone alert is quite ugly, this tool does the job, it gets users into itunes where they can rate your app, however, when compared to something like the facebook connect dialog box it just looks abit pants.

Id love to make one myself but time is a valuable commodity at present, perhaps in the future..