# iphone:how to implement rate the app popup for iphone app every 5th time user opens up app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, app-store

I need to implement the rate tha app popup when user every 5th time open the app
user can also give review

and then i need to redirect him to page of iTunes

Comment: I thought this was against Apple's guidelines?

Comment: It's probably against the user's wishes, at least. If you write a good app, users will want to rate it. If you bug them to rate it...

Comment: that means we should not popup rate alert to user every 5th time.we should leave it on him to rate,right?

Comment: I have a feeling I read somewhere in Apple's guidelines that the don't want you to prompt the user to rate the app.  That being said, I've seen quite a few apps that do that, but perhaps it's just because Apple don't know because it doesn't come up the first time they run it?

Comment: no it asks it at every 5th time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone app rating popup code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437544/iphone-app-rating-popup-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the excellent [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/) library. The `APPIRATER_USES_UNTIL_PROMPT` constant in `Appirater.h` defines often the prompt appears. The prompt reappears in new versions of your app!

Comment: IRate is also worth a look, (similar

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 10.3+ the right way to request app reviews is through SKStoreReviewController, which is Apple's official way of requesting App Store ratings and reviews from users.

Simply call:

```
[SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
```

More details on the class: [SKStoreReviewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller)